# What is this markup in node.html.twig?

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

In node.twig.html (Bootstrap) I am seeing the code below and I am unsure of it's purpose. It is causing a problem with a view mode that I need to theme.

Is it important? Can I get rid of it?

```
<h2{{ title_attributes }}>
  <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
</h2>
```

Comment: This is a linked node title. You don’t need it. {{ label }} refers to the node title.

Comment: This will print sub title of page. It depends on your requirement.

Answer (score -2):

this is the node title.

the h2 should be kept on every page if you are concerned about SEO

Comment: This is wrong. It's not a field label, it's a node title, or entity label.